# Access nested span element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the class of a nested span element, when clicking a certain item.
[JSFiddle goes here](https://jsfiddle.net/snoodaard/p5wumysa/1/).

HTML:

```
<div id="title_1" class="title">Title 1</div>
<span id="foo_1" class="foo">
    foo contents<br />
    <span class="bar">bar contents</span>
    <br /><br />
</span>

<div id="title_2" class="title">Title 2</div>
<span id="foo_2" class="foo">
    foo contents<br />
    <span class="bar">bar contents</span>
    <br /><br />
</span>
```

Changing the class of the first span is possible though `$(this).nextAll('.foo:first').addClass('highlight');` like I'm doing in the current JSFiddle.

However I want to change the class of 'bar' element only.

Among some things of what I tried:

```
$(this).nextAll('.foo:first .bar:first').addClass('highlight');
$(this).nextAll('.foo .bar:first').addClass('highlight');
$(this).nextAll('.foo:first').nextAll('.bar:first').addClass('highlight');
$(this).next('.foo').next('.bar').addClass('highlight');
```

... all without success.

I think I'm missing something basic here. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/nez0cvsm/

Just change `nextAll()` with `next()` (to access the span after the title) and then add `.children()` (to access the span inside the span). I used children instead of "find" supposing that inside that span there will be only another one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to have more than one span and only want to select the ones with the bar class you can use the following:

```
$(this).next().children('.bar').addClass('highlight');
```

Example here (with extra span): https://jsfiddle.net/1ekrjqk1/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use next and then find the element with class `bar`

```
$(this).next('.foo').find('.bar').addClass('highlight');
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/yssusqq9/